# Iterating huge xml in java

Tags: java, xml, refactoring

I am trying to read and iterate information of a huge xml and try to convert into json and send it to front end. There are many child elements and sub-child elements in the response XML. I want to iterate the values of one child "Node" and its child and convert into JSON and send it to front end for converting it into excel. Currently, I am able to achieve this by using nested for-loops. However, as the number of sub-child increases, the for-loop also increases.

```
for(X s:a){
  for(A a: B){
     for(B b:C){
 } 
}
}
```

Is there any other way to write cleaner code?

Comment: Sounds to me like you are looking for the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

Comment: Please quantify "huge". It can mean anything from 1Mb to 1Tb, which is a rather significant difference.

Comment: Huge in terms of number lines of xml code. It has 8500 to 10000 lines of XML data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use recursions. Pseudo code:

```
void getAllChildren(StackOfChildren stack, Node node) {
   if(node.hasChildNode)
      getAllChildren(stack, node); 

   stack.add(node);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know your root element then start with it and check its child element exists or not, if exists then iterate it.Below could be your algorithm to read XML file.

```
Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(dataString)));

NodeList newDataSetList = document.getElementsByTagName("NewDataSet");
readChildNodes(NodeList newDataSetList)

public void readChildNodes(NodeList newDataSetList){
for(int i=0;i<newDataSetList.getLength(); i++) {
    Node tableNode = newDataSetList.item(i);
    NodeList tableDataList = tableNode.getChildNodes();
    readChildNodes(tableDataList);
    System.out.println(tableNode.getNodeName());
}
}
```

You can recursively call each element to fetch its child element, no need to have inner for or while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not using the right tool for the job.

Have you tried using XSLT? This allows to transform XML into anything else, by declaring transformation rules.
However, it is relying on DOM (the Document Object Model) and load the whole file in memory.

Alternatively, you could use SAX (Simple API for XML) which does not load the whole document at once.

Other alternatives exist too, like StAX, which I think is more efficient memory wise.